# Opendtect installation error

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install Opendtect in Ubuntu and I am finding the following error during installation:

```
Err: Corrupt survey: missing directory: /tmp/Seismics
Err: Cannot open user settings file for write
    Cannot open '/home/dibakar/.od/settings.new' for write
Err: Cannot open user settings file for write
    Cannot open '/home/dibakar/.od/settings.new' for write
```

Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? Which version of Opendtect are you trying to install? How are you trying to install it? (did you download a .deb of another installer? What version was the installer?)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and opendetect 4.6.0.

Comment: thank you. i got the answer. One must change the permission of .od files.

Answer (score 1):

Got this from Dibakar Ghosal his comment:

You have to change the permissions of the .od files. Make them writable.